# process html with gulp and mathjax

Tags: javascript, html, svg, gulp, mathjax

I like to use mathjax in gulp for rendering formula as svg. the problem is that mathjax (gulp-mathjax-node) create svg embedded into html page. My idea is to create link of external svg image created by MathJax.

eg:

from

```html
<div> this is the formula: $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$</div>
```

to

```html
<div> this is the formula: <img src="463749.svg" /></div>
```

there's something which can help me to do this?

Comment: I don't think mathjax will do that. The root document must be html.

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to export svg embedded inside html but I'm encuntering some probs